# How do I implement a custom UITextInputTokenizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, tokenize

I have a UITextView and am using its tokenizer to check which words the user taps on.

My goal is to change what the tokenizer thinks of as a word. Currently it seems to define words as consecutive alphanumeric characters, I want a word to be defined as consecutive characters that aren't a space character (" ").

For example: 'foo-bar', 'foo/bar' and 'foo@@bar' will all currently be treated as two separate words ('foo' and 'bar') but I want them all to be treated as a single word (as none of them contain spaces).

The documentation talks about subclassing the UITextInputStringTokenizer class but I can't find a single example of someone doing this and I can't figure out how I would go about implementing the required methods:

```
func isPosition(position: UITextPosition, atBoundary granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> Bool

func isPosition(position: UITextPosition, withinTextUnit granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> Bool

func positionFromPosition(position: UITextPosition, toBoundary granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> UITextPosition?

func rangeEnclosingPosition(position: UITextPosition, withGranularity granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> UITextRange?
```

Comment: You ever figure out an answer to this?

Comment: How about using regular Expression for that? This can help --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052465/3061689

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, create your implementation that extends `UITextInputStringTokenizer` and leave most methods untouched (or just calling `super`)

You just need to override `isPosition(_:atBoundary:inDirection:)` and `isPosition(_:withinTextUnit:inDirection:)` when granularity is word to check if the characters next to that position are considered to be in a word boundary, i.e., alphanumeric character and space together. The default implementation will return `true` also for other non-spaces that are considered not part of a word, you instead consider those as forming part of a word.
When granularity is not word, you can default to `super` as well.

Answer (score 1):

// Create a subclass of UITextInputStringTokenizer
class CustomTokenizer: UITextInputStringTokenizer {

```
// Override the rangeEnclosingPosition method so that it looks for characters that are not a space (" ")
override func rangeEnclosingPosition(position: UITextPosition, withGranularity granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> UITextRange? {
    // First check if the range enclosing the position is not nil
    guard let range = super.rangeEnclosingPosition(position: position, withGranularity: granularity, inDirection: direction) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Then define a string of characters that are not a space (" ")
    let nonSpaceCharacterSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")
    
    // Then define a range which will be used to search for the non space characters
    let startIndex = range.start
    let endIndex = range.end
    let searchRange = startIndex..<endIndex
    
    // Then define a string based on the range
    let text = self.textInput.text(in: searchRange)
    
    // Then search the string for any characters that are not a space (" ")
    if let _ = text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: nonSpaceCharacterSet) {
        // If any characters that are not a space (" ") are found, then return the range
        return range
    } else {
        // Otherwise, return nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

// Then set the tokenizer of the UITextView to the CustomTokenizer
textView.tokenizer = CustomTokenizer(textInput: textView)

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement a custom `UITextInputTokenizer` you can either create an entirely new class that implements the `UITextInputTokenizer` protocol or you can subclass `UITextInputStringTokenizer`. Since you only want to change what the tokenizer thinks of as a word it is simpler to subclass `UITextInputStringTokenizer` and implement the required methods like so:

```swift
class MyUITextInputStringTokenizer: UITextInputStringTokenizer {
    weak var textInput: (UIResponder & UITextInput)? = nil

    override init(textInput: UIResponder & UITextInput) {
        self.textInput = textInput
        super.init(textInput: textInput)
    }


    // MARK: required methods to override
        override func isPosition(_ position: UITextPosition, atBoundary granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> Bool {
        guard let textInput = textInput else {
            return false
        }
        if granularity == .word {
            guard let start = textInput.position(from: position, offset: -1) else {
                // position is at the beginning of the document
                guard let end = textInput.position(from: position, offset: 1) else {
                    // the document is empty
                    return false
                }
                guard let range = textInput.textRange(from: position, to: end) else {
                    return false
                }
                guard let text = textInput.text(in: range) else {
                    return false
                }
                if direction == .storage(.forward) || direction == .layout(.right) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return !self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.startIndex])
                }
            }
            guard let end = textInput.position(from: position, offset: 1) else {
                // position is at the end of a nonempty document
                guard let range = textInput.textRange(from: start, to: position) else {
                    return false
                }
                guard let text = textInput.text(in: range) else {
                    return false
                }
                if direction == .storage(.forward) || direction == .layout(.right) {
                    return !self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.startIndex])
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            guard let range = textInput.textRange(from: start, to: end) else {
                return false
            }
            guard let text = textInput.text(in: range) else {
                return false
            }
            if direction == .storage(.forward) || direction == .layout(.right) {
                return !self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.startIndex]) && self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.index(before: text.endIndex)])
            } else {
                return self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.startIndex]) && !self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.index(before: text.endIndex)])
            }
        } else {
            return super.isPosition(position, atBoundary: granularity, inDirection: direction)
        }
    }

    override func isPosition(_ position: UITextPosition, withinTextUnit granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> Bool {
        guard let textInput = textInput else {
            return false
        }
        if granularity == .word {
            var offset = 1
            if direction == .storage(.backward) || direction == .layout(.left) {
                offset = -1
            }
            let start = position
            guard let end = textInput.position(from: position, offset: offset) else {
                return false
            }
            guard let range = textInput.textRange(from: start , to: end) else {
                return false
            }
            guard let text = textInput.text(in: range) else {
                return false
            }
            return !self.charIsWhitespace(text[text.startIndex])
        } else {
            return super.isPosition(position, withinTextUnit: granularity, inDirection: direction)
        }
    }

    override func position(from position: UITextPosition, toBoundary granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> UITextPosition? {
        guard let textInput = textInput else {
            return nil
        }
        if granularity == .word {
            var offset = 1
            if direction == .storage(.backward) || direction == .layout(.left) {
                offset = -1
            }

            var pos = position
            while let newPos = textInput.position(from: pos, offset: offset) {
                pos = newPos
                if self.isPosition(newPos, atBoundary: .word, inDirection: .storage(.forward)) || self.isPosition(newPos, atBoundary: .word, inDirection: .storage(.backward)) {
                    break
                }
            }
            return pos
        } else {
            return super.position(from: position, toBoundary: granularity, inDirection: direction)
        }
    }

    override func rangeEnclosingPosition(_ position: UITextPosition, with granularity: UITextGranularity, inDirection direction: UITextDirection) -> UITextRange? {
        guard let textInput = textInput else {
            return nil
        }
        if granularity == .word {
            let start = self.find(textInput: textInput, position: position, direction: .backward, condition: self.charIsWhitespace)
            let end = self.find(textInput: textInput, position: position, direction: .forward, condition: self.charIsWhitespace)
            if textInput.compare(start, to: end) == .orderedSame {
                return nil
            }
            return textInput.textRange(from: start, to: end)
        } else {
            return super.rangeEnclosingPosition(position, with: granularity, inDirection: direction)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Helper methods
    func find(textInput: UITextInput, position: UITextPosition, direction: UITextStorageDirection, condition: (Character) -> Bool) -> UITextPosition {
        let offset = direction == .forward ? 1 : -1
        var pos = position
        while let newPos = textInput.position(from: pos, offset: offset) {
            guard let range = textInput.textRange(from: pos, to: newPos) else {
                break
            }
            guard let text = textInput.text(in: range) else {
                break
            }
            if condition(text[text.startIndex]) {
                break
            }
            pos = newPos
        }
        return pos
    }

    func charIsWhitespace(_ ch: Character) -> Bool {
        return ch == " "
    }
}
```

In the overriden functions if `granularity` is equal to `.word` we provide our own implementation. Otherwise we use the one from `UITextInputStringTokenizer`. The `textInput` property needs to be declared as `weak` in order to avoid retain cycles.

`UITextInput` objects generally do not provide a public setter for their `tokenizer` property. To use this tokenizer with e.g. an `UITextView` you have to subclass `UITextView`, override it's getter and return an instance of it in the getter.

```swift
class MyUITextView: UITextView {
    lazy var _tokenizer: UITextInputTokenizer = MyUITextInputStringTokenizer(textInput: self)
    override var tokenizer: UITextInputTokenizer {
        get {
            return _tokenizer
        }
    }
}
```

When being called with `granularity` as `.word`, the overridden functions are expected to behave as follows:

The function `rangeEnclosingPosition(_, with:, inDirection:)` is expected to return a `UITextRange` containing `position` whose text is a word or `nil` if no such range exists.

`position(from:, toBoundary:, inDirection:)` returns the position of the next word boundary in `direction`. More precisely it is supposed to return the next position in `direction`, that is a word boundary in any direction.

`isPosition(, withinTextUnit:, inDirection:)` is expected to return `true` if `position` is located within a word. On positions that are also word boundaries this function should return `true` if the word is located relative to `position` in same direction as `direction`.

`isPosition(, atBoundary:, inDirection:)` should return `true` if `position` is a word boundary. In this implementation a position is a word boundary if no word is present in `direction` and if a word is present in the opposite direction to `direction`.