# Swift - Getting only AlphaNumeric Characters from String

Tags: swift, regex, swift4

I'm trying to create an internal function for the `String` class to get only AlphaNumeric characters and return a string. I'm running into a few errors with how to convert the matches back into a string using Regex. Can someone tell me how to fix the code or if there's an easier way?

I want something like this

```
let testString = "_<$abc$>_"
let alphaNumericString = testString.alphaNumeric() //abc
```

So far I have:

```
extension String {
    internal func alphaNumeric() -> String {
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^a-z0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let string = self as NSString
        let results = regex?.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))
        let matches = results.map {
            String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!])
        }
        return matches.join()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove any char other than ASCII letters and digits from a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I only want ASCII letters and digits. Essentially the 26 letters and 10 digits

Comment: So, you expect `abc` as a result of processing the `_<$abc$>_` string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, just abc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may directly use `replacingOccurrences` (that removes all non-overlapping matches from the input string) with `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` pattern:

```
let str = "_<$abc$>_"
let pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]+"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
print(result) // => abc
```

The `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` pattern is a *negated character class* that matches any char but the ones defined in the class, one or more occurrences (due to `+` quantifier).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P89eKT/1).

Answer (score 11):

Try below extension:

```
extension String {
    var alphanumeric: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined().lowercased()
    }
}
```

Usage: `print("alphanumeric :", "_<$abc$>_".alphanumeric)`

Output : abc

Comment: `CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted` is clever, nice one.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use characterset for this like

```
extension String {
    var alphaNumeric: String {
       components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined()` **should not work** for special characters like Japanese...

Below should work. Tested

```
extension String {    
    var toAlphaNumeric: String {
        let pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]+"
        
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
    }
}

print("Ad asd asdaあsだsd123".toAlphaNumeric)

Result: Adasdasdassd123
```

You can change `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` to `[^A-Za-z]+` or `[^0-9]+`